# Why does my Hub always show the turnstile animation when I navigate (back) to the page?

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I've got a simple page set up:

```
<Page ...stuff goes here...>
    <Hub>
        <Hub.Header>
            <views:HubHeaderView />
        </Hub.Header>
        <HubSection x:Name="PrimaryViewSection">
            <DataTemplate>
                <views:PrimaryHubView />
            </DataTemplate>
        </HubSection>
    </Hub>
</Page>
```

Every time I navigate to this page, on first view and when I hit the back button after further navigation, I always get the turnstile animation. It looks really ugly since the `Hub` control is so wide. The problem is, I've tried clearing all the `Transitions` and `ChildrenTransitions` that I can find, and none of them seem to be the right one. What do I have to do to make the `Hub` not animate like this?

Comment: Does every page you have show this animation when you navigate? I think in windows phone 8.1(winrt) some animations are inserted in the rootFrame. You might want to check your app.xaml.cs file

Comment: No, it's only that specific page. It *appears* to be just the `Hub`. when I get back in front of my dev machine later I'll see if that same page acts that way if the `Hub` is removed and replaced with a generic `Grid`.

Comment: Whoops, forgot to come back and comment. It's definitely the `Hub`. If I wrap it with a `Grid` with a garish color (like magenta), then I see the `Grid`'s background color while the `Hub` animates in on top.

Comment: The last thing I can propose is to take the default template of the hub (you can find it in generic.xaml) and strip it bare of anything that looks like it could cause the effect. Sometimes it can be an inner control in the template. Sorry I coulndn't be of more help.

Comment: Thanks @Corcus, that's what I've done already. The best I can do is remove the `PlaneProjection` that causes the turnstile animation, but it still slides in from the side with a really too-long animation time. I'll keep playing with it, if I find a solution I'll come back and post it.